# Why does the INERT SEP take so long to deploy?

Tags: turboprop, icing, anti-ice

I have experience in Microsoft Flight Simulator with the Daher TBM 930. It has an inertial separator, which I use for de-icing in the simulator. I watched a video on it, and I understand how it works, but don't get why it takes 40 seconds to deploy. It's pretty simple, only a valve opening in the turbofan and another thing coming down to redirect particles into the valve.

So why does such a simple mechanism take such a long time to deploy? Maybe I am not fully understanding how it works?

Answer (score 4):

Well you can get it straight from the horse’s mouth…

Due to the strong aerodynamic loads on the movable doors, the inertial separator uses an electrically driven screw jack to open or close the inertial separator.  In addition, fast movement of the IPS doors can cause severe disruption of the air flow to the engine, potentially causing a flame out or compressor stall.  Therefore actuation is delayed and takes place gradually. It takes a period of time – approximately 40 seconds, for the IPS to move through its full range of motion.

Comment: Yeah, that's the video I watched. But thanks for your answer, now I get it!